# Microsoft Identity Web generating http instead of https for redirect_url

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, azure-authentication, microsoft-identity-web

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC app and I want to use Azure B2C authentication.

The redirect_url that's being generated has `http` instead of `https` like so:

```
&redirect_uri=**http**%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com%2Fsignin-oidc
```

This should be `https`, and it's causing this error:

> AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '9dbe40e0-7555-4ddf-9c17-b5218ed6ca89'.

My `appsettings.json` looks like this:

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxx",
    "ClientId": "xxxx",
    "TenantId": "xxxx",
    "ClientSecret": "xxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/"
}
```

and my code in `Startup.cs` is like so:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");
```

For some reason this works fine on my dev machine with localhost (redirect_url=https) but on the server it's always `http`.

Any ideas? This has been driving me crazy all day

**EDIT: RESOLVED!**  Turns out the issue was that I didn't have a HTTPS binding in IIS, only a HTTP binding...  strange, since I was accessing the site via https://... - I guess somehow the IIS gave a certificate and allowed HTTPS even though I didn't have a binding for it

Comment: Have you tried adding `http://myapp.com/signin-oidc` to your Azure AD App? You can do it via microsoft  graph api. it is not recommended for production , but it's ok just for test

Comment: I though of that too... but it only allows localhost to be http... forces me to put https

Comment: I see, if so, I am afraid you should enable HTTPS  for your server

Comment: This isn't the issue.. the server does have HTTPS enabled, and has a valid SSL certificate installed

Comment: I see, Have your tried this sample? You can specify redirect URL easily in `appsettings.json` : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/tree/master

Comment: @ZhiLv  I think it should be the AAD B2c portal.

Comment: @CarlZhao, yes, you are right, thanks for reminding me about that.

Comment: Open Azure portal, go to Azure AD B2C tenant and check the app's Redirect URI and the RedirectUri in the appsettings.json file, they should use the same URI. Reference: [ASP.NET Core web app with Azure AD B2C](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/an-aspnet-core-web-app-with-azure-ad-b2c/) and [How to secure a Web API built with ASP.NET Core using Azure AD B2C](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/how-to-secure-a-web-api-built-with-aspnet-core-using-the-azure-ad-b2c/).

Comment: Are you using the right setting from launchSettings.json? There are two settings; one for HTTP; one for https?

Comment: I've tripple-checked to make sure Azure portal Redirect URI matches appsettings.json file... it's definitely correct and the same.

I don't know what launchSettings.json is rbrayb - do you mean appsettings? If so, I didn't know there was one for http and https - can you please tell me more.

Doing a google search I found this bug:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/115

... this seems like the same thing, but I'm using the latest version and this bug has been closed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys!

Turns out that this was caused because I didn't have a HTTPS binding in IIS.

I was accessing the site via HTTPS, so not sure how IIS allowed that, but adding a HTTPS binding fixed the redirect_uri problem